# screenshots stageros

Tags: ros, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.Like the title says I don't know how to save screenshots from stageros.I mean, I've tried from View->Save screenshots (one time to start recording and another time to stop like I read in Stage manual) but I can't find the saved file,if it saves something since it seems to me that it doesn't..also it doesn't ask me for a path to save files.
So how can I do this?
Thanks everyone

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33869/screenshots-stageros/) by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I never used stage save screenshot. That said, if it is a punctual save, I suggest using the printscreen of your keyboard.
You may also record a video, using [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on 2012-05-12**:
ok thanks Procopio